# Store path to dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, path

How might one store the path to a value in a `dict` of `dict`s? For instance, we can easily store the path to the `name` value in a variable `name_field`:

```
person = {}
person['name'] = 'Jeff Atwood'
person['address'] = {}
person['address']['street'] = 'Main Street'
person['address']['zip'] = '12345'
person['address']['city'] = 'Miami'

# Get name
name_field = 'name'
print( person[name_field] )
```

How might the path to the `city` value be stored?

```
# Get city
city_field = ['address', 'city']
print( person[city_field] )  // Obviously won't work!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function to do this

```
print reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], city_field, person)
```

**Output**

```
Miami
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer is very concise and non-invasive to the rest of the code. Also, it teaches me a new tool. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
path = ('address', 'city')
lookup = person
for key in path:
    lookup = lookup[key]

print lookup
# gives: Miami
```

This will raise a `KeyError` if a part of the path does not exist.

It will also work if `path` consists of one value, such as `('name',)`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that uses Simeon's (and Unubtu's deleted answer) is to create your own dict class that defines an extra method:

```
class mydict(dict):
    def lookup(self, *args):
        tmp = self
        for field in args:
            tmp = tmp[field]
        return tmp

person = mydict()
person['name'] = 'Jeff Atwood'
person['address'] = {}
person['address']['street'] = 'Main Street'
person['address']['zip'] = '12345'
person['address']['city'] = 'Miami'

print(person.lookup('address', 'city'))
print(person.lookup('name'))
print(person.lookup('city'))
```

which results in:

```
Miami
Jeff Atwood
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "look.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(person.lookup('city'))
  File "look.py", line 5, in lookup
    tmp = tmp[field]
KeyError: 'city'
```

You can shorten the loop per the suggestion of thefourtheye. If you want to be really fancy, you can probably override private methods like `__get__` to allow for a case like `person['address', 'city']`, but then things may become tricky.

Comment: Thank you Evert! This really shows off the power of extending Python built-in classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way - behaves exactly the same as Simeon Visser's

```
from operator import itemgetter
pget = lambda map, path: reduce(lambda x,p: itemgetter(p)(x), path, map)
```

With your example data:

```
person = {
  'name': 'Jeff Atwood',
  'address': {
    'street': 'Main Street',
    'zip': '12345',
    'city': 'Miami',
  },
}

pget(person, ('address', 'zip')) # Prints '12345'
pget(person, ('name',))          # Prints 'Jeff Atwood'
pget(person, ('nope',))          # Raises KeyError
```

Comment: Nice idea to define the lambda function outside the place where it is used, to keep the code cleaner. Thanks.