# Store path to dictionary value for setting value

Tags: python, dictionary, path

Consider a dict that holds a person:

```
person = {}
person['name'] = 'Jeff Atwood'
person['address'] = {}
person['address']['street'] = 'Main Street'
person['address']['zip'] = '12345'
person['address']['city'] = 'Miami'
```

**How might the path to a location in the dictionary be stored for writing to the value?**

```
# Set city (Existing field)
city_field = ['address', 'city']
person[city_field] = 'London'  // Obviously won't work!

# Set country (New field)
country_field = ['address', 'country']
person[city_country] = 'UK'  // Obviously won't work!
```

Note that I had previously asked [how to store the path to dictionary value for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812325/store-path-to-dictionary-value).

Comment: Seems like a good use case for a class

Comment: I think there's no a built-in feature for that. Either you can extend `dict` to achieve it, use a class, use a helper function, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Actually my co-worker Moshe is the brains behind this one:

```
def set_path(someDict, path, value):
    for x in path[::-1]:
        value = {x: value}
    return deepupdate(someDict, value)


def deepupdate(original, update):
    for key, value in original.items(): 
        if not key in update:
            update[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            deepupdate(value, update[key]) 
    return update


person = {}
person = set_path(person, ['name'], 'Shalom')
person = set_path(person, ['address', 'city'], 'Toronto')
person = set_path(person, ['address', 'street'], 'Baddessa')

pprint(person)
```

Returns:

```
{
    'address': {
        'city': 'Toronto',
        'street': 'Baddessa'
    },
    'name': 'Shalom'
}
```

This depends on user Stanislav's excellent [recursive dictionary deepmerge() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression/8310229#8310229).

Answer (score 1):

Use tuples as index.

```
city_field = ('address', 'city')    
country_field = ('address', 'country')
```

Usage:

```
>>> person = {}
>>> city_field = ('address', 'city')    
>>> country_field = ('address', 'country')
>>> person[city_field] = 'Miami'
>>> person[country_field] = 'UK'
>>> person
{('address', 'country'): 'UK', ('address', 'city'): 'Miami'}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this won't help with existing dictionaries which are already being used.